# Need help resolving the loop issue

Tags: javascript

I recently started learning Javascript, enjoying it a lot. So, after learning some info about loops, i decided to improve a simple Rock, Scissors, Paper game. The improvement is to keep player wins and computer wins values as variables, and than loop the function until playerScore variable reaches value of 10. Im not so good at syntax yet, though trying to get the general logic and where i've made a mistake.

To reach my goal, i've declared two variables - playerScore and computerScore, their initial value is 0. After each player win or computer win i decided to add + 1 to variable.

Than start the game, i've declared a function playGame() and looped it using While. The loop seems infinite and more than that, current results are not logging to console. Any help is much appreciated, will help me to understand the logic much more than any courses i've passed.

Here's the code:

```
var playerScore = 0;
var computerScore = 0;

function getUserChoice() {
  var userInput = prompt('Choose stone, scissors or paper');
  userInput = userInput.toLowerCase();
  if(userInput === 'stone' || userInput === 'paper' || userInput === 'scissors' || userInput === 'bomb') {
    return userInput;
  }
  else {

    alert('Error! Choose stone, scissors or paper!');

  }
}

function getComputerChoice() {
 var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() *3);
  if(randomNumber === 1) {
    return 'stone';
  }

  else if(randomNumber === 2) {
    return 'paper';
  }

  else {
    return 'scissors';

  }
}


function determineWinner (userChoice, computerChoice) {
  if(userChoice === computerChoice) {
    return 'That's a tie!';
  }

  if(userChoice === 'stone') {
    if(computerChoice === 'scissors') {

      playerScore = playerScore + 1;
      сonsole.log(playerScore);
      console.log(computerScore);
      return 'Player won!';


    }
    else {
      if(computerChoice === 'paper') {

      computerScore = computerScore + 1;
      сonsole.log(playerScore);
      console.log(computerScore);

        return 'Computer won!'

      }
    }
  }

  if(userChoice === 'paper') {
    if(computerChoice === 'scissors') {
      computerScore = computerScore + 1;
      сonsole.log(playerScore);
      console.log(computerScore);
      return 'Computer won!';
    }
    else {
      if(computerChoice === 'stone') {
      playerScore = playerScore + 1;
      сonsole.log(playerScore);
      console.log(computerScore);
      return 'Player wonи!';
    }
    }
      }
  if(userChoice === 'scissors') {
    if(computerChoice === 'stone') {
      computerScore = computerScore + 1;
      сonsole.log(playerScore);
      console.log(computerScore);    
      return 'Computer won!';
    }
    else {
      if(computerChoice === 'paper') {
      playerScore = playerScore + 1;
      сonsole.log(playerScore);
      console.log(computerScore); 
      return 'Player won!';
      }
    }
      }

      if(userChoice === 'bomb') {
        if(computerChoice === 'stone' || computerChoice === 'scissors' || computerChoice === 'paper') {
     playerScore = playerScore + 1;
      сonsole.log(playerScore);
      console.log(computerScore); 
      return 'Player won!';
          return 'Player won!';

        }
      }

  }


while(playerScore < 10) {
function playGame() {
  var userChoice = getUserChoice();
  var computerChoice = getComputerChoice();
  alert('Player chose' + ' ' + userChoice + '!');
 alert('Computer chose' + ' ' + computerChoice + '!');

 alert(determineWinner(userChoice, computerChoice));
 playGame() = false;
}
};



playGame();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to move your while-loop into the function `playGame()`.

```
function playGame() {
  while(playerScore < 10) {
    var userChoice = getUserChoice();
    var computerChoice = getComputerChoice();
    alert('Player chose' + ' ' + userChoice + '!');
    alert('Computer chose' + ' ' + computerChoice + '!');

    alert(determineWinner(userChoice, computerChoice));
  }
}
```

Comment: Big thanks, that worked! Another thing i wanted to do is to track current scores for both computer and player. In `function determineWinner`, in every if/else statement i've added  `console.log(playerScore);
   console.log(computerScore);`, but it only shows the results to console when the loop is finished, not "online". Any obvious way to fix this?

Comment: You have to give the browser `time to breathe`. To do that you have to remove the `while` loop and use things like `setTimeout` or `setInterval`.